# How to get the maximum inode limit supported by a filesystem in java?

Tags: java, filesystems

I want to get the number of inodes used up in a filesystem so that i know when i am about to hit the max . This is because my application creates a lot of (order of millions maybe ) of small files .

I came over UnixOperatingSystemMXBean . But that only gives fileDescriptors i guess ..

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `df -i` to find this out.  Most file systems can easily handle millions of files, however its usually very inefficient.  I would suggest you try stiring data in larger files.

Comment: Thanks Peter for the reply . Yes , df -i will give it . But , what i want is a Java API that i can use to get the same info about a filesystem . No need to work on all platforms , but in *nix at least .